# Calculating a vector perpendicular to a unit vector

Tags: vectors

"find unit vector **x** in direction of **w** = (2,1,2)"  then "find vector perpendicular to **x**"

so I calculate **x** as  **w**/length(**w**) = **w**/sqrt(2^2 + 1^2 + 2^2) = **w**/sqrt(9) = **w**/3

and a perpendicular vector of **w** = 1/3(2,1,2) could be =  1/3(1,-2,0)

Strangely, the answer key gives the perpendicular as 1/sqrt(5)(1,-2,0)

Is this an error or are my calculation mechanics wrong somewhere?

Comment: You are both right. The answer key gives a *unit* vector perpendicular to $x$.

Comment: oh yeah...  when i calculate the magnitude of their answer, it's 1.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector perpendicular to the given vector $W$ is $X=(x,y,z)$ such that it satisfies

$W.X=0$

which implies values of (x,y,z) can be such that

$2x+y+2z=0$

There are infinitely many vectors which satisfies above equation.

Both, your answer and text book answer is correct since they satisfy the above equation.